# Get source code for dynamic webpage using curl call

Tags: php, curl

I am getting the source code for a particular web page.
But I am not getting some dynamic content.
Is there any way to wait until page load and then get the source code.
I need a solution in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting the source code for a particular web page. But I am not getting some dynamic content.

Dynamic contents will be loaded mostly only after making an ajax call in a webpage. If you want to get those data using curl, then you should inspect the network call that's being made from that webpage and replicate that call in curl.

> Is there any way to wait until page load and then get the source code

Even though you get the full source code of the page via curl, you won't get the dynamically loaded content.

Otherwise, you can use tools like selenium to get those data.

Comment: @Progi1990 is this answer helpful? Let me know if you want any further clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but isn't there any way by which I can wait to load all page content and then grab all code! I know we can't use curl here but without using any Tool like selenium don't we get dynamic data? :(

Comment: I am not sure if there any tool like you ask. If you don't want to use a real browser with selenium then you can go for a headless browser like phantom js.